# Using Netsh with PsExec

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to dump DHCP settings from an older server thats being decommissioned. I ran the command fine while on the actual server but when trying to run it using psexec remotely, it keeps failing. The command is: psexec \\$source netsh dhcp server \\$source dump>$dhcpSettings

$source = the server being decommissioned
$dhcpSettings = the path to save the dumped settings

I've tried all sorts of combinations of encapsulating quotation marks but still nothing. the errors I'm getting is, "The system cannot find the file specified" and "The system cannot find the path specified"

EDIT: So I got rid of the path to save the dumped settings and now it works. But how should I format the command so that it'll save the settings to the remote computer's C:\USER.SET\LOG directory?

Comment: Are you using psexec b/c PowerShell remoting is not available to you?
What is the exact command you are running right now?

Comment: @AdilH. I'm using PsExec because that was what my colleagues recommended I use. The command that I got to work, which sent all the input to the PS console, is psexec \\$source netsh dhcp server \\$source dump
When I add > $outputFile after dump is when it just doesn't work anymore. I guess I could just pipe the output using Out-File instead of using the netsh syntax?

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to bundle the command you want to run and the stdout redirection into a single line cmd file and use PsExec -c or -f to copy and execute that file on the remote system. As an example

Create a line cmd file named DHCPSettings.cmd with the following in it and save it to C:\temp\:

```
netsh dhcp server \\localhost dump >c:\user.set\log\dhcpsetting.log
```

Then use

```
psexec \\$source -c c:\temp\DHCPSettings.cmd
```

You did not really provide any code to go by and I am not sure I understand the all requirements and constraints you have, so consider this as an idea; not the exact commands you need to run. Hope it helps.